How do I create a character removal button from the DataStorer in Roblox Studio?
how to create a button that wakes up to delete a character from the memory of the database and replace it with the DataStorer character. The character is on this path.ReplicatedStorage.Characters.Common.Citizen.
my problem is that the citizen is not saved to the DataStorer
script button:
local button = script.Parent
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- Define the spawn location
local spawnLocation = workspace:WaitForChild("SpawnLocation") -- Make sure you have a SpawnLocation part in your workspace

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
  local player = Players.LocalPlayer
  local character = player.Character

  if character then
    character:Destroy()
  end

  -- Clone the new character and set it up
  local newCharacter = ReplicatedStorage.Characters.Common.Citizen:Clone()
  newCharacter.Name = player.Name  -- Ensure the character has the player's name
  newCharacter.Parent = workspace
  player.Character = newCharacter

  -- Wait for the character to be set up before making adjustments
  newCharacter:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
  newCharacter:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

  -- Move the new character to the spawn location
  newCharacter:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(spawnLocation.CFrame)

  -- Set the camera to follow the new character
  workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraSubject = newCharacter:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
  workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
end)

DataStorer_DataStore:
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local config = script:WaitForChild("datastore_config")
local myDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("$Data$!"..config:FindFirstChild("DataVersion").Value)

local saving = config:FindFirstChild("Saving")
local autoSave = config:FindFirstChild("AutoSave")

local function create_table(plr)
    local player_stats = {}

    for _, folder in pairs(script:FindFirstChild("Plr"):GetChildren()) do 
        if folder:IsA("Folder") then
            print(folder)
            for _, stat in pairs(plr:FindFirstChild(folder.Name):GetChildren()) do
                player_stats[stat.Name.." "..folder.Name] = stat.Value
            end
        end
    end

    return player_stats
end

local function saveData(plr)
    local player_stats = create_table(plr)

    local succes, err = pcall(function()
        local key = plr.UserId.."'s' Data"
        myDataStore:SetAsync(key, player_stats)
    end)

    if succes then
        print("Saved Data Correctly!")
    else
        warn(err)
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local key = plr.UserId.."'s' Data"
    local data = myDataStore:GetAsync(key)

    print(data)

    for _, folder in pairs(script:FindFirstChild("Plr"):GetChildren()) do

        if folder:IsA("Folder") then

            local fc = folder:Clone()
            fc.Parent = plr

            if saving.Value == true then
                for _, item in pairs(fc:GetChildren()) do           
                    if data then
                        item.Value = data[item.Name.." "..folder.Name]
                        continue
                    else
                        warn("There is no data!")
                        continue
                    end
                end             
            end
        end
        
        while autoSave.Value > 0 do
            task.wait(autoSave.Value * 60)
            saveData(plr)
            print("Saved", data)
        end
        
    end
end)


game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    if saving.Value == true then
        saveData(plr)
    end
end)

The database contains all the data.
If you need additional information, I will answer in the comments
